# SQL subquery aggregation analogy

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a working example of a SQL query:

```
SELECT a.user_id, a.latitude, a.longitude, a.accuracy, a.heading, a.speed, a.created_at 
FROM `location` a 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, MAX(`created_at`) created_at
    FROM location
    WHERE created_at > :date
    GROUP BY `user_id`
) b ON a.`user_id` = b.`user_id` AND a.`created_at` = b.`created_at`
```

which selects todays last location for each user

How can I perform this query in MongoDB?

I got the first part of it (subquery) in php:

```
$mongodb->getCollection('location')->aggregate([
    ['$match' => ['created_at' => ['$gte' => $beginOfDay]]],
    [
        '$group' => [
            '_id' => '$user_id', 
            'lastTime' => ['$max' => '$created_at']
        ]
    ]
]);
```

and would't want to create new queries...

Maybe in MongoDB it's done easily than in a relational DB?

Comment: What is the collection format/shape ans desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to do it differently instead of mapping the SQL query. Below is the aggregation.

```
db.location.aggregate([
 {$match : {$gte : beginOfDay}},
 {$sort : {'user_id' : 1, 'created_at' : -1}},
 {$group : {
         _id : '$user_id', 
         created_at: { $first: "$created_at" }, 
         latitude: { $first: "$latitude" }, 
         longitude: { $first: "$longitude" },
         // ....similarly other fields
        }
 }
]);
```

What it basically does is aggregate by filtering all the document which has user with data created on the day then sorting by user_id and descending created_at and after that in group stage, for each user_id it gets the first document data with the help of [$first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) operator.

I am not sure how to transform into php way or if php driver allows $first or not for sure but worth a try.

Comment: yes, it works!
Final result:
`$locations = $mongodb->getCollection('location')->aggregate([['$match' => ['created_at' => ['$gte' => $beginOfDay]]], ['$sort' => ['created_at' => -1]], ['$group' => ['_id' => '$user_id', 'latitude' => ['$first' => '$latitude'], 'longitude' => ['$first' => '$longitude'], 'accuracy' => ['$first' => '$accuracy'], 'heading' => ['$first' => '$heading'], 'speed' => ['$first' => '$speed'], 'created_at' => ['$first' => '$created_at']]]]);
`

Comment: Other question, how can I get insted of `_id` the `user_id` key?

Comment: Glad it helped, I would say add one more field in group stage something like 'user_id' => ['$first' => '$user_id'], in that case you will get both _id and user_id as the value of user_id. if you want the original _id of the document, I would use something like 'o_id' => ['$first' => '$_id']. I guess these should work.